# making SQL update query

Tags: mysql

i have sql table of columns id,version,setting_key,setting_value

and i want to change the `default_encoding`from `LATIN1`to `UTF8`for all `mcs`(13 or 14 or 15 or .. )

i made this

```
UPDATE bo_user_setting SET setting_value = 'UTF8' WHERE setting_key = 'DEFAULT_ENCODING';
```

but it doesn't work .. any help ??

thanks in advance

Comment: do you want to execute this query in java or do you want to know whether this query is correct or not

Comment: ^^ table or column *alter*

Comment: @Boola yess i am executing it in java and nothing happen to the table

Answer (score 0):

You need alter table not update

```
  ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```